# Joomla 3.6.2 -- Modify Registration Page and Plugin User Profile

Tags: joomla-3.6, registration, profile, com-banners

I wish to modify the Joomla! Registration Page.  Specifically:

1. Modify the page title
2. Add a Banner across the top of the page
3. Move captcha to the bottom of "User Profile" above the "register" or "cancel" buttons.

I located the file: `com_users\views\registration\temp\default.php` and the line `<?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page_heading')); ?>`.

Questions:

1. Where is the value "page_heading" obtained from?
2. Will removing (or modifying the above line) cause other issues?
3. What file or files(s) can I modify to perform point **3** above?

If these questions seem very elementary, they should be I am just a beginner in PHP and CSS.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't edit core files, but use the nice feature of template override within joomla. Help e.g from https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides and many other documents.
In your case: Copy the file `com_users/views/registration/temp/default.php` to `templates/[your template_name]/html/com_users/default.php`.
Afterwards, you can edit this new file, and the joomla core will still work and any update of joomla does not touch this file.

ad 1: 
`$this->params->get('page_heading')`; the parameter "page_heading" is set through file com_users/views/registration/view.html.php (in line 87ff, Joomla 3.6.2)
 `if ($menu)
        {
            $this->params->def('page_heading', $this->params->get('page_title', $menu->title));
        }
        else
        {
            $this->params->def('page_heading', JText::_('COM_USERS_REGISTRATION'));
        }`

ad 2:
Removing which line? You may change the page heading in your file `templates/[your template_name]/html/com_users/default.php` - no problem.

ad 3:
same as point 2.

Comment: Thank you.  After reviewing your edit, I am unable to complete my task.  NOT due to your response, but due to my limited knowledge of PHP.  I am headed back to the books before I take on my project.  Thank you again.